# How do I send in Teams Proactive Messages to user?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send a private message to a user on teams.

I've checked several resources, but still have problems.

Using this sampel https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-proactive-messaging I've tried the following.

1. ngrok http -host-header=rewrite 5000
2. Upload manifest.zip to teams
3. Update coordinate-logger/appsettings
4. Run coordinate-logger
5. dotnet run -- sendUserMessage --app-id="{{Bot Id}}" --app-password="{{Bot Password}}" --service-url="{{ServiceUrl}}" --conversation-id="{{Conversation Id}}" --message="Send Message to a User"

Bot Id = appId

Bot Password = secret

service-url = ngrok host ( ngrok http://e4438bf4e8ed.ngrok.io )

conversation-id = my user's team guid

I'm getting 404 on http://e4438bf4e8ed.ngrok.io/v3/conversations/xxxxxxx-59c1-45d2-829d-069fefda33bf/activities

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your serviceUrl - it's not supposed to be a link to your OWN service - it's meant to be the unique ServiceUrl for the particular conversation in question. Teams has a few of these, based on where the tenant is located (e.g. "NAM" for North America"). You need to get the one specific for your conversation, in the same way that you get the `conversationId`. Without being familiar with this particular sample you're using, I'd guess that it's part of the 'coordinate-logger' project.

The ServiceUrl should look something like this: https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/ or https://smba.trafficmanager.net/nam/ or similar.

To explain why this is important, you might find it worthwhile to read a blog post I've got about how the calls work. It doesn't discuss proactive messaging per se, but it's relevant nonetheless. See https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work .

[update: adding some format examples]
The conversation id looks a bit different based on the type of conversation (1-1, group chat, or Teams channel), but it should look similar to one of these:

- 1-1 chat: a:1gUrQbVe1BjcpZePQ6m.......[long value]
- group chat: 19:0a5b1b32cc54402[other bits]@thread.v2
- channel: 19:ac23ff62cc54402[other bits]@thread.skype

Comment: Why is it so hard, to achieve a 'hello world' proactive message, I'm starting to lose hope here.

Comment: Like many things, once you've done it a couple of times, it starts to make much more sense, but it certainly is a bit tricky to get your head around, especially at first.

Comment: I got the region from the user, where i get the conversationId, added the region as so  https://smba.trafficmanager.net/region , but it didn't work . Do you know any simple working example to help me send a message to a teams user?

Comment: what's the 404 showing (the full url)? Might be a '/' missing?

Comment: Unhandled exception: Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.SendToConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: I mean can you show the full address, like you did in your original question (you can redact the app id, I just want to see that the first part is all correct).

Comment: `dotnet run -- sendUserMessage --app-id="xxxxxxxx-2c74-46fe-bc1c-b46827cde6fb" --app-password="xxxxxxxxxxxxxkIGPE-y_3E43ll-s_8" --service-url="https://smba.trafficmanager.net/ro/" --conversation-id="xxxxxxxx-59c1-45d2-829d-069fefda33bf" --message="Send Message to a User"`

Comment: ok thanks. What is the final address it's mapping to, do you know? I'm looking for something like this: https://smba.trafficmanager.net/ro/v3/conversations/xxxxxxx-59c1-45d2-829d-069fefda33bf/activities . How did you get that address before? Can you debug the code and check that it's correct?

Comment: This is the request endpoint  `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/ro/v3/conversations/xxxxxxxx-59c1-45d2-829d-069fefda33bf/activities`, HttpPost

Comment: ok,looking more at the other values now. --service-url="https://smba.trafficmanager.net/ro/" looks correct. Your conversation Id looks wrong though. It's format changes based on the conversation type (e.g. 1-1 chat with a user, or a group chat, or a channel in Teams), but none of them looks just like a plain guid, like what you've got there.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some sample conversation Ids

Comment: Can i please ask, how do I get 1-1 chat id ?

Comment: In all 3 cases, there needs to -be- a conversation, and the bot needs to have -permisson- to send to it. For a group chat or channel, the conversation -exists-, but the bot app MUST be added to the conversation, otherwise it won't have permissions. For the 1-1, the 'conversation' only comes into existence when the user installs the bot apps into "personal" scope (e.g. basically the left menu).

Comment: When the bot is added, it receives an event, where it is sent the Conversation Id, ServiceUrl, and other possibly useful info, like Locale Id for language, timezone settings, etc.